# Deleting a managed bean causes some weird situation in JSF

Tags: jsf

I had a managed bean called controlBean and i deleted it. Then i tried to add a new bean with the same name. I also had deleted it from faces-config.xml file, which was looking like this:

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>controlBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.app.managedbeans.ControlBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

The problem is, even though i specify its name as controlBean again, NetBeans calls it controlBean1, and if i delete and add again it is called controlBean2 etc. Does anyone know the reason? What can i see to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: What is the IDE you use. I had a similar issue with Netbeans 7.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check you have added a default constructors for other managed beans. 
I had the same issue with Netbeans 7.3. I have used annotations instead in that case. I added some methods to the few other beans. Stopped the GlassFish server. Deleted the dis and build folders manually. Clean and build the project again. Ant that error was not there for the time being. Don't know the exact cause. I had to do this few times for other beans as well. 
If still not response, create a new bean and let it be there until a proper solution is available.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of all this XML and use the @ManagedBean annotation.

Comment: you mean faces-config.xml or web.xml file? and then after deletin should i add again?

Comment: These two questions are both completely pointless. I meant what I wrote. You must already know where the XML you cited was. 'Get rid of' doesn't really need further clarification either.

Comment: IMO I would also suggest using Eclipse instead of Netbeans for JSF development.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza The remark seems irrelevant, not to mention very possibly impractical. I use NetBeans and I don't have these problems.